# Corona: display zoomable vector files (like .pdf)

Tags: vector, lua, zooming, coronasdk

Is it possible to display a zoomable vector file in Corona?

Specifically: I'd like to display a map in an app I am building, and I'd like it to be a vector rather than an image so that the resolution remains the same as the user zooms in or out.

If anyone has an alternate method to get this result I'm interested in that too.

Answer (score 0):

CoronaSDK doesn't have a "vector format loader" built in, but is able to draw lines, polygons, circles and the like - you can get more information here:

http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/factory-functions

With this in mind, you could create your own custom format (in Lua, probably) saying things like "draw a line from here to here" or "there is a circle with this size on this position".

For zooming in/out, you could just add a "parent" for all your graphical objects, call it "map", and use map.scale - http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/objectscale